# How to left align a dataframe column in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Have to left align a description column in the pandas dataframe in python. Similar to left or right align a cell in excel sheet. is there any solution for this? Image attached for reference.

[!Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8Psu.png)

Comment: Try giving some more detail about the specifics of your problem and what you've tried. It's not clear exactly what the screenshot is showing and what you're trying to achieve

Comment: Description column in the dataset is right aligned. I just need left align it. Like how we use in excel left align,right align a cell.

Comment: a pandas DataFrame is an in memory table structure so has no concept of alignment. It looks like you're displaying it in some way but not clear in your question/screenshot how this is being done. So it's likely a display setting you need to change

Comment: Okay understood. Thank you. I have updated the question and image.

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
df.style.set_properties(subset=["col1", "col2"], **{'text-align': 'right'})
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you can just remove the leading spaces.

```
df.Description = df.Description.apply(lambda row: row.lstrip(' '))
```