# Dataframe left align

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new and starting learning python.

can someone help me how to set sql data with dataframe to left align?

This is my script:

```
SQL_Query = pd.read_sql_query("""Select Distinct(TEMPLATE_DESCRIPTION) 'PRODUCE LETTER', COUNT(TEMPLATE_DESCRIPTION) 'COUNT'
from LETTER_REQUEST LR JOIN ACCOUNT AC ON LR.ACCOUNT_ID = AC.ACCOUNT_ID AND ADDRESS_TYPE !='EMAL'
Where SENT > (SELECT( GETDATE()-2))
GROUP BY TEMPLATE_DESCRIPTION, CONVERT(date,[SENT])""",conn)

print()
df = pd.DataFrame(SQL_Query)
print(df)
```

Here's my sql output.

```
                       PRODUCE LETTER  COUNT
0                   1st Arrears Letter      5
1                   2nd Arrears Letter      2
2                    Alteration Letter     13
```

I want this result:

```
PRODUCE LETTER          COUNT
1st Arrears Letter      5
2nd Arrears Letter      2
Alteration Letter      13
```

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53460941/how-to-left-align-a-dataframe-column-in-python

Comment: try the code but still not working

Comment: `style` works only in Jupyter because `style` uses `CSS` for console may try `print( df.to_string(formatters={'PRODUCE LETTER': "{:<20s}".format}) )` but it use hardcoded length `20` and I don't know method to get max text length in column