# How to export a column from a dataframe to a text file with left alignment in Python Pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, string, text, text-alignment

I have a xlsx file. The text format in it is normal, everything aligning to the left. Now I want to extract a string column from it and save it into a txt file. My codes are as below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_excel('excel_file.xlsx', 
                   sheet_name ='tab1'
                   )

df = df.drop(['L1','L2','L3'], axis=1)

# so that only 1 string column is left

w = open("output.txt", "w")
 
w.write (df.to_string(index=False, header=False))
 
w.close()
```

Ok, i have successfully created a text file. But my problem is, everything in this file is aligning to the right with many empty spaces in the front of each text string. A sample is as below,

```
          Michael Jordan
          Scottie Pippen
                    Dirk
                   Curry
```

What I want is the normal txt file format like this:

```
Michael Jordan
Scottie Pippen
Dirk
Curry
```

Left alignment without any format.

Would anyone please help?
I have already tried many other solutions like set_properties, set_styles, etc, and have read many posts like this [How to left align a dataframe column in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53460941/how-to-left-align-a-dataframe-column-in-python), but my problem is not solved.

Comment: You only have one column, so just use `df.to_csv("output.txt", index=False, header=False)` instead?

Comment: shxt! how can this be so easy? I totally didn't not to_csv can be used to save as txt file. Thank you @Timus

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your column you want to write is named `COLUMN_NAME`, you can do:

```py
with open("output.txt", "w") as f_out:
    f_out.write("\n".join(df["COLUMN_NAME"]))
```

This creates `output.txt`:

```
Michael Jordan
Scottie Pippen
Dirk
```